# Is it possible to save/persist data from an Einstein Dataset back to Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-experience, einstein-analytics, einstein, saql, dataflow

We are building a Lightning application that will be used to show Einstein consolidated data to users.

We want to either consume this data directly from Einstein (we know we can do that with Wave SDK and stuff, but that's not the first option) or persist the result of a SAQL query back to custom objects.

Is the second option possible?

Thanks in advance!